# i have .wav file. i want to break that file into parts

Tags: iphone, core-audio, audio-streaming

i have .wav file. i want to break that file into parts. is there any way to do it please let me know.. thanks in advance....

thank you

Comment: You can edit a wav file in Audacity, the open-source wave file editor, but I'm guessing that's not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Please be a little clearer; You want to do this code-wise i think? Where do you get that .wav file? What do you want to split it for, and cant you do that with a external program like Ken and Joshua named?

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about quality I would use the free application Audacity. If you are just looking to make a ringtone, google "ringtone splitter". There are many freeware and open source apps to split music files easily.